#   Is there a known way to formalise notion that certain theorems are essential ones?   

Tags: proof-assistants, proof-theory, metamathematics

- **Suppose You ask a question beginning from "Why some structure is..." or "Why some object has property..." and several
  answers arises. Which criteria do You
  use to qualify which answer is correct?**

For example [here](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/mizar/) You may find interesting picture (gzipped postscript file) of [proofs formalized in Mizar system.](http://www.cs.ru.nl/~freek/mizar/mml.ps.gz). Mizar library of formalized theorems is really [huge](http://www.mizar.org/JFM/mmlident.html). On the picture You may see, that theorems arises from other and are used in proofs of another ones, forming big graph of structure of theorems formalized in Mizar so far. If I may read something from this graph, there is no theorem which will have more that 3 or 4 incoming edges what means there is no theorem which is used in more that 3 or 4 proofs. Of course there are some with 5 incoming edges, but in fact there is many theorems which have more or less equal number of incoming edges, which may mean that most theorems are equivalently important. Maybe it should be measured by tree deepness? Maybe there is something like Google page rank algorithm for theorems?

Probably we would like to have such relation: "theorems recognized as important should be influential, or foundational for broad area of theory".

- **I understand that one may believe that this is a real state of matter,
  but are there any strict results
  based on real data in this matter?**

By real data I mean at best **proof theory** analysis, or even **citation analysis**, but not someone opinion (which of course may be enlightening and inspirational). I would like to learn something **about structure of deductive theories**, and not about "real practice". It is the same as in real life: we try to measure risks, and income rate not based on someone opinion but on facts. Could we know the facts here?

It seems from Mizar graph ( which is the only one accessible for me in this area) I could not find any object which will correspond to our intuition of importance of theorems. Maybe this is effect of present Mizar state of affair, and in bigger/other system, some theorems begin central one? Are there any conditions to state such position?

- **What about other proof assistants, as
  Isabelle or COQ. Is there any similar
  graph from other systems suitable for
  such analysis?**

Comment: Kakaz, you're asking a lot of questions here.  (I count 16.)  I suspect you'll get a better response if you make the question much shorter and more focussed.  At present I find it very difficult to see what would qualify as a definitive answer.

Comment: Yes that is true, You are right, I am sorry for that reason. It is because I have much trouble to ask it in correct way. I would like to ask questions which nobody asks. It seems that most of it is related to meta or logic. It is difficult to ask question precise in this matter without explanation. It seems that even such clear question as about definition of general quantifier was down voted although solution is known at least from 57 year see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16095/is-there-formal-definition-of-universal-quantification

Comment: probably down vote is easier that understand;-) but asking is easier than answer;-)

Comment: maybe now it is more acceptable?

Comment: The only source I have is Mizar project.I do not know any graph of relations between formalized theorems within some theory. As Mizar is not very widely known, I leave some remarks about it.

Comment: Just to clarify my earlier comment, which I think could now be misinterpreted: it referred to the original version of the question, which contained about 16 subquestions.  When I said "you're asking a lot of questions here", the word "here" didn't mean MO.

Comment: Ah, I understand. As I misinterpret Your question in exactly this way, I still think both of us was be right;-) However I wish to thank You: now question looks better.

Comment: May I polite ask for causes of such decision? I ask for properties of certain and known approach: formalized reverse mathematic. I ask for known aspect of it: If You need reconstruct formal proof You have to define in formal way every object You use. As You close this is that mean this is not related to mathematics, non interesting, not in area of research by anybody or simply not known?

Comment: For what it's worth, I find this question very interesting, and also would like to know how one can distinguish formally which theorems are 'important'. 

It may be that instead of looking at how often a theorem is used, one could look at how many different proofs there are for a given theorem (i.e number of outgoing edges). The example I'm thinking of is quadratic reciprocity. It would be interesting to see a graph that tries to show all proofs of simpler theorems, rather than one proof of a hard theorem.

Comment: I suppose it may be essential to our understanding of what mathematic is. We usually connect validity of theorem with its "importance" for a theory. But I do not have any reason for such connection. In my opinion theorems are important because our creativity, for pure aesthetic means. Probably I am conventionalist. But I would like to see if it is only my opinion or fact. It is worth to check if we can. As we begin with computerized proof systems it may be used here but there is important question: is this approach objective and general or it is particular property of certain comp. system?. 

Comment: Also for what it's worth, I think that whether a theorem is "important" is subjective, and to a certain extent also controlled by fashion within mathematics---which areas are currently moving fast due to clear motivations and goals and so on. I hence think that there is no formal way for deciding whether a theorem is important.


Comment: OK, Thank You Kevin, that is interesting opinion. As I well understand You state that there is no formal way to decide if certain theorem is important. I also share Your opinion: in my opinion much of the mathematics importance is subjective rather than objective. But note that there is Google page rank algorithm which in pure formal way gives us importance of web pages usually in agree with our opinion. Do You know any research in this area related to proof theory, theories structure etc?

Comment: @Kevin--One can imagine a setup based on PageRank. While (most) theorems are tautologies, some are more closely related than others. Some get used elsewhere in actual human proofs quite a bit, most not so much. So, make a list of the theorems in the literature (easier said than done, of course, even in principle b/c of variations on individual theorems) and make them vertices. Put a directed edge when one theorem is used to prove another. Then use PageRank to order the theorems based on their utility in the actual literature. 

Comment: @Steve: this is exactly idea behind this question. Then You may use any reverse mathematic framework, like Mizar, or some formalizations present in libraries for coq, or Isabele ( if they have one, I do not know) and try to measure it in objective way. Of course question how far it is matter of certain framework ( book) and how far it is objective. but is it not interesting?

Comment: @Steve, Kevin: as I presume You like the question: why do upvote it?

Comment: Interesting part is to see how "computed" output of for example PageRank (or other computations) is different from mainstream opinion.

Comment: Kakaz, The answer to your question (which I am unable to post since unfortunately it is closed) is the subject of logic known as Reverse Mathematics. In this subject, one investigates which axioms are provably required for all the various classical theorems of mathematics, and it turns out that over a very weak base theory, there are precisely five groups of statements, all of which are equivalent. That is, there are precisely five classical theorems, such that nearly every classical theorem is provably *equivalent* to one of them (and one could use any of these equivalents in place).

Comment: See Reverse Mathematics at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics

Comment: @Joel:Ha! That is shocking for me, to get such definitive answer here! I am not sure if it could be strict accepted as answer here but definitely it is very interesting interpretation indeed. Thank You a lot! Take a note that during discussion here: tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/287/… Scott Morrison states very interesting opinion, which is worth of thinking I suppose. As Scot mention possible ways of decomposition of mathematical truth into theorems it is very interesting context/relation here. Your interpretation of my question takes us back into axioms as roots of tree of certain theory.

Comment: My opinion is that many questions that may seem vague or ill-posed or overly philosophical at first can often turn out to have very precise mathematical answers, when thought about in the right way.

Comment: @Joel I agree with You, in Poland we sometimes say that there is no stupid questions, only answers. But commenting Your answer: I have read Simpson webpage where I found interesting sequence: "The foundations of X are not necessarily the most interesting part of field X." Your answer is the **real first** for my question ( example of formalization what is that mean "important" here in sense "fundamental" theorem). As it is interesting I will try to reopen. But it is not the only possible answer. We may "localize"  my question to certain theory, not to whole mathematic.

Comment: Joel- I'm not sure I really agree that what you've written actually answers kakaz's question (it, for example, doesn't involve any actual data about what theorems mathematicians actually use), but I've reopened the question so you have a chance to answer.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, I appreciate it. I explain in my answer how Reverse Mathematics seems to answer the question in an even better way than could be possible by looking at such data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Although your question is vague in certain ways, one robust answer to it is provided by the subject known as [Reverse Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics). The nature of this answer is different from what you had suggested or solicited, in that it is not based on any observed data of mathematical practice, but rather is based on the provable logical relations among the classical theorems of mathematics. Thus, it is a mathematical answer, rather than an engineering answer.

The project of Reverse Mathematics is to reverse the usual process of mathematics, by proving the axioms from the theorems, rather than the theorems from the axioms. Thus, one comes to know exactly which axioms are required for which theorems. These reversals have now been carried out for an enormous number of the classical theorems of mathematics, and a rich subject is developing. (Harvey Friedman and Steve Simpson among others are prominent researchers in this area.)

The main, perhaps surprising conclusion of the project of Reverse Mathematics is that it turns out that almost every theorem of classical mathematics is provably equivalent, over a very weak base theory, to one of five possibilities. That is, most of the theorems of classical mathematics turn out to be equivalent to each other in five large equivalence classes.

For example,

- Provable in and equivalent to the theory RCA<sub>0</sub> (and each other) are: basic properties of the natural/rational numbers, the Baire Cateogory theorem, the Intermediate Value theorem, the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, the existence of the algebraic closure of a countable field, etc. etc. etc.
- Equivalent to WKL<sub>0</sub> (and each other) are the Heine Borel theorem, the Brouer fixed-point theorem, the Hahn-Banach theorem, the Jordan curve theorem, the uniqueness of algebraic closures, etc. , etc. etc.
- Equivalent to ACA<sub>0</sub> (and each other) are the Bolzano-Weierstraus theorem, Ascoli's theorem, sequential completeness of the reals, existence of transcendental basis for countable fields, Konig's lemma, etc., etc.
- Equivalent to ATR<sub>0</sub> (and each other) are the comparability of countable well orderings, Ulm's theorem, Lusin's separation theorem, Determinacy for open sets, etc.
- Equivalent to Π<sup>1</sup><sub>1</sub> comprehension (and each other) are the Cantor-Bendixion theorem and the theorem that every Abelian group is the direct sum of a divisible group and a reduced group, etc.

The naturality and canonical nature of these five axiom systems is proved by the fact that they are equivalent to so many different classical theorems of mathematics. At the same time, these results prove that those theorems themselves are natural and essential in the sense of the title of your question.

The overall lesson of Reverse mathematics is the fact that there are not actually so many different theorems, in a strictly logical sense, since these theorems all turn out to be logically equivalent to each other in those five categories. In this sense, there are essentially only five theorems, and these are all essential. But their essential nature is mutable, in the sense that any of them could be replaced by any other within the same class.

I take this as a robust answer to the question that you asked (and perhaps it fulfills your remark that you thought ideally the answer would come from proof theory). The essential nature of those five classes of theorems is not proved by looking at their citation statistics in the google page-rank style, however, but by considering their logical structure and the fact that they are logically equivalent to each other over a very weak base theory.

Finally, let me say that of course, the Reverse Mathematicians have by now discovered various exceptions to the five classes, and it is now no longer fully true to say that ALL of the known reversals fit so neatly into those categories. The exceptional theorems are often very interesting cases which do not fit into the otherwise canonical categories.

Comment: Your answer is very interesting, and in some sense globally, which means that You answer regards to the whole mathematics. I would like to state certain objections to Your very good answer. **First** :It is nearly ideal answer, and I learn a lot after recognizing this approach. But, as You may find at Simpson webpage, and within his publications, he states that is not the case that "fundamental theorems" are necessary "the most interesting ones". So as we know by reverse mathematics which theorems are ** fundamental ** we still do not know what ** "the interesting" ** mean

Comment: **Second** : as every mathematical theory may be regarded as more or less separated one ( I know it is disputable), there should be explicite criteria which allows us at least to perform exactly the same analysis as with reverse mathematics but localized only to certain theory, for example only for complex functions. We may think of stating axioms for such theory ( and it may be different than $RCA_0$ etc), and still we may look for criteria of importance. So as Your answer may be concerned as great example of some approach it is not description of the method.

Comment: **Third** : during discussion with Scot Morison on meta he states: "the trivial answer that there is no natural decomposition of mathematical truth into "theorem" nuggets, and the granularity of a chosen decomposition is just as much (actually, maybe more so!) a product of the social environment". I would be appreciated if he or someone else may say something similar here. Is that true that there is no such decomposition, so only relation to axioms are the only possible here? So I state this clear as last question in comment below.

Comment: Is that true that there is no natural decomposition of mathematical truth into theorems? Is that true that the only natural is dichotomy axioms -  theorems, where axioms are given and known, whilst theorems are only particular way of description of theory? Are theorems only arbitrary chosen kind of notation for consequences of axioms? 

Comment: So Joel, let me wait for a few hours maybe someone will say here something interesting. If not I will accept Your answer because it is obviously useful and at least formally correct.

Comment: @Joel: I also not understand this part: "by considering their logical structure and the fact that they are logically equivalent to each other over a very weak base theory." As far as I understand wikipedia article, they form a hierarchical system. So last one $\Pi^{1}_{1}$ is the strongest and allows for example proof of consistency of previous four classes. What then equivalence means?